# need clarification about coding semantic orientation between aspects and opinion words

Tags: java, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Inorder to identify the sentiment score of the sentence Sentiwordnet is used. But when implementing every aspect has to be given the score based on the sentiment expression value. how to score the aspect based on sentiment word.For example The music player is great. here in this sentence music player is scored with sentiment value of great. but when it is "The music player of this phone is great",whether to score for phone or music player. How to implement this in java when multiple sentences are taken. How to map the aspects and opinion words in a sentence

Comment: Just to give you an idea of how hard this problems is, here's an example to show that it can't be done purely with syntax: (a) The music player of this phone is great. (b) The violin player of this orchestra is great.

In (a), the sentiment is associated with the phone, but in (b), it's clearly associated with the player.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear.. i want to implement this in java.. if not such complex reviews, atleast simple reviews like "The phone is excellent". here i have to score the aspect phone with sentiment value of "excellent". Help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

The task is not an easy one and too large to fit in the margin of this answer, but you can start by looking at SemEval-2014 Task 4: Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis papers (http://anthology.aclweb.org/S/S14/S14-2.pdf#page=47) to get a direction of posible solution.

Comment: It may work for some cases, you can see this kind of solution implemented in www.aspectiva.com

Comment: Yes sir i viewed the implementation in www.aspectiva.com How to code it in java...To map the aspects with corresponding sentiment words..